What's the function Q32 in this schematic? - Waveshare E-Paper driver
As I understand, the EPD_RST signal controls the BJT (Q32) which controls the FET (Q31). In my setup I have EPD_RST connected to an IO on an ESP32 and VCC_INT connected to 3V3.
My question is, is Q32 actually needed? If so what's its purpose? Can the gate of the FET just be directly controlled by the ESP32 IO?
Original schematic "Waveshare 7.3inch e-Paper HAT":
https://files.waveshare.com/upload/0/0c/7.3inch_e-Paper_HAT.pdf


If Vcc is greater than the control signal high level, then Q32 functions as a level shifter. But I can't find anything in your question or link that specifies the voltages.

@Mattman944  The VCC_INT in the original schematic is 5V from RPi.  If you Ctrl-F the VCC_INT in the linked PDF, you'd find it.  [That's badly drawn "object oriented" schematic.]

@Spoons See also this question regarding the purpose of Q32: on-going quest to understand p-channel MOSFETs.

Thanks for the replies. I was overlooking the rpi connection. In my setup that connector isn't being used and I have an ESP32 connected through P2. So VCC_INT in my case is 3V3.
But as @Chester Gillon pointed out, the manual actually mentions 5V is required for Power (VCC_INT). So I guess if I was using this correctly Q32 would be needed anyways.

The 7.3inch e-Paper HAT schematic shows the VCC_INT net is connected to RPI_5V, and the parameters section of the 7.3inch e-Paper HAT (G) Manual contains the following for Operating voltage:

5V is required for power and signal

Therefore, VCC_INT which is the source of Q31 is at 5 V.
The datasheet for the AO3401 used for Q31 shows the following for the Gate Threshold Voltage:

Which means for Q31 to be turned off the gate voltage needs to get within -0.5 V of the source voltage. I.e. with VCC_INT as 5 V a ESP32 GPIO connected to the gate of Q31 would need to have a high voltage of 4.5 V to  5 V in order to ensure Q31 was off.
The ESP32 operates with VDD of 3.3 V, and the datasheet gives VOH High-level output voltage as a minimum of 0.8×VDD. Therefore, the minimum High-level output voltage of a ESP32 GPIO is 2.64 V.

Can the gate of the FET just be directly controlled by the ESP32 IO?

Given the above analysis, the answer is No since the ESP32 GPIO High-level output voltage is not high enough to guarantee Q31 can be switched off.

Properly not. To turn on the Q31 you could pull your GPIO pin low. But to turn it off you have to make the VGS less than the threshold value. This could mean pulling the gate to same voltage level as the source of Q31. The transistor Q32 does this job by pulling the gate low and become high impedance to pull the gate of Q31 to the source voltage of Q31.
